# Windows 10 IoT Core - UWP - send email background

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

How do you send an email in a Win10 IoT app (UWP) in the background for a headed application without showing an email app?

I see there is an EmailMessage and EmailManager class available but this only has:

```
EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync()
```

> Launches the email application with a new message displayed.

Comment: If you have access to this class, maybe it'll help you. [MailMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't send E-Mail through `EmailManager` API without user interaction. 
You need to use `SmtpClient` to do so.

Like this:

```
public static void SendMail(MailMessage Message)
{
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Host = "smtp.googlemail.com";
    client.Port = 587;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "password");
    client.Send(Message); 
}
```

Or better check the microsoft example: [Send Email with Attachment in C# from Windows Store Apps - XAML - UWP](https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/c_xaml.aspx?cat=6)

Comment: Thanks i didn't know about the EASendMail nuget package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/EASendMail/